# Is there a C++ equivalent to np.frombuffer?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

I'm reading some data from a radar through a simple STM32 blue pill MCU.
I have some code examples written i Python and Matlab and translating it into C++.

One thing I can't get working correctly is the following bit. The Python code:

```
TDAT_Distance = np.frombuffer(com_obj.read(2), dtype=np.uint16)
```

I'm receiving a UINT16 little endian.
TDAT_Distance is the variable
The value of np.frombuffer reads 2 bytes from serial and sets the datatype.

In C++ I tried reading the bytes into an array without the desired result.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I think the closest equivalent would be casting the raw contents from com_obj.read to a uint16_t.

Answer (score 0):

If the read returns (a pointer to) bytes that are properly aligned and match the endianness of your system, you can `reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(com_obj.read(sizeof(uint16_t)));`.

That might not be likely, so you can instead construct an `uint16_t` with the right value

```
uint16_t from_le_bytes(const unsigned char * bytes)
{
    return bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8);
}
```

Comment: Where does from_le_bytes() come from?

Comment: @MichaelSurette that's a definition of a function, so right there

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I don't readily know how to apply this to my code but I'll read up on it and get back with a conclusion!

Comment: As it turns out I don't have to cast anything as the values are properly formatted as they are received. It creates an ARRAY of all new headaches but at least I understand it now. 
Thank you again for the suggestions, it opened new insights!